# MAX_MEMBERS_EXCEEDED The maximum number of members for the account has been exceeded

Tags: docusignapi

While trying to add user in the User Management, I'm getting this error. Currently I'm having only one user. Is there any user limit for trial account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Production environment trial accounts have much more strict limits than Sandbox accounts. When accessing DocuSign, are you doing so from a production url (`account.docusign.com`) or Demo (`account-d.docusign.com`)?

If you are accessing the Production environment, I would recommend registering for a Developer Sandbox account here: https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

@Rkumar there is no limit on adding new users in the demo account.
Check your existing user privileges in case you have changed something
Please follow this guide https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-users when adding users